# JavaScript match() regex not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to use JavaScript match() function in order to get three numerical values from a string.

An example of the string: `doSomething(14754572,782339,2,'')`

And here's the JavaScript I'm using, but with no results:

```
var $numbers = $onclick.match(/(\d*),(\d*),(\d)/);
var first = $numbers[0] // Should be 14754572 
var second = $numbers[1] // Should be 782339
var third = $numbers[2] // Should be 2
```

I'm guessing that the regex is not ok...

Comment: The regex is [correct](https://regex101.com/r/rS3aP9/1). You yourself write *first* and then access `[0]`th group holding the entire match value. See https://jsfiddle.net/mz900rfb/ where the indices are in accordance with your expected results.

Comment: did you try define new Reg and find .match ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex is fine, it's just that your indexes into the match array are incorrect. The first entry, `[0]`, is the **full** text that matched (`"14754572,782339,2"` in your case). Then the capture groups you've defined are given afterward, in `[1]`, `[2]`, and `[3]`. So you just need to adjust those indexes.

```js
var $onclick = "doSomething(14754572,782339,2,'')";
var $numbers = $onclick.match(/(\d*),(\d*),(\d)/);
console.log($numbers[1]); // 14754572 
// Note ------------^^^
console.log($numbers[2]); // 782339
// Note ------------^^^
console.log($numbers[3]); // 2
// Note ------------^^^
```

Just FWIW, that regex is not tolerant of optional whitespace, so you might consider adding `\s*` in there; additionally, I might update it to require the leading `(`:

```
// Leading ( ------------------vv
var $numbers = $onclick.match(/\(\s*(\d*)\s*,\s*(\d*)\s*,\s*(\d)/);
// Optional whitespace ----------^^^-----^^^-^^^-----^^^-^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you log $numbers you'll see that it evaluates to all matches of the regex. Hence this, what you need to do is to select index 1, 2 and 3 instead of 0, 1 and 2:

```
var $numbers = $onclick.match(/(\d*),(\d*),(\d)/);
var first = $numbers[1] // Returns 14754572 
var second = $numbers[2] // Returns 782339
var third = $numbers[3] // Returns 2
console.log('1:'+first,' 2:'+second,' 3:'+third);
```